# when I use jest to test react component it throws "Invariant Violation:Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

my code is

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react'
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Tooltip extends React.Component {
  childRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    const child = React.Children.only(props.children);

    const trigger = React.cloneElement(
      child,
      {ref: this.childRef, 'data-tip': this.props.title}
    )

    if (!props.title) {
      return trigger
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        {trigger}
        <ReactTooltip place={props.placement} effect="solid"/>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

Tooltip.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  placement: PropTypes.string,
}

Tooltip.defaultProps = {
  placement: 'bottom',
}

export default Tooltip
```

and my test is :

```
import React from 'react'
import {mount} from "enzyme"

import {Tooltip} from "../../../../../main/js/app/components/ui/Tooltip"
describe('Tooltip', () => {
    let props ,tooltip
    beforeEach(() => {
        props = {
            title: 'test title',
            placement: 'bottom',
            children: <div/>
        }
        tooltip= mount(<Tooltip {...props}/>)
    })

    it('should render', () => {
        // jest.fn(React.Children.only(props.children))
        // const child = React.Children.only(props.children);
        // const  reactTooltip =tooltip.find(ReactTooltip)
       // expect(reactTooltip).toContain("bottom")
    })
})
```

when I run the test,it throws error: 
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to import the named export (`Tooltip` from `export default Tooltip`), this should fix it:

```
import Tooltip from "../../../../../main/js/app/components/ui/Tooltip"
```

However, if you only with to import the `Tooltip` class, you will need to export the class component itself,

```
export class Tooltip extends React.Component {
 // the rest 
}
```

Followed by importing only the class component, rather than the default export.

```
import { Tooltip } from "../../../../../main/js/app/components/ui/Tooltip"
```